# ASP.NET Core Edit action does not update new info

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have calculations that are currently in model, as I am trying to find an efficient place to store my calculations, here is the model

```
public class Worker
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public double Q1Rev {get;set;}
    public double Q2Rev {get;set;}
    public double Q1Cost {get;set;}
    public double Q2Cost {get;set;}

    public double Q1Profit{
       get
       {
           return Q1Rev - Q1Cost;
       }
    }
    public double Q2Profit
    {
        get
        {
            return Q2Rev - Q2Cost;
        }
    }
}
```

In my `Edit` action of my controller, if I only want to edit the Q1Rev for example, it allows me to do so however my Q1Profit and Q2Profit will now be set to '0' instead of preserving the original or the actual number `Q1Profit = Q1Rev - Q1Cost`. Instead it is just sets `Q1Profit = 0`. Here is the edit controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,UserId,Q1Rev,Q2Rev,Q1Cost,Q2Cost,Q1Profit,Q2Profit")] Worker worker)
    {
        if (id != worker.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(worker);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!WorkerExists(worker.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(worker);
    }
```

How can I change it so everytime I `Create` a new one or `Edit` an already existing property it calculates everything properly? So it calculates `Q1Profit = Q1Rev - Q1Cost` after I edit one of the values. Instead I want it to save my new values and actually perform the calculation for the new `Q1Profit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that in the controller if i want to save the new values and perform the new calculations, I need to add specifically the values that I am adding in the controller like so

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,UserId,Q1Rev,Q2Rev,Q1Cost,Q2Cost,Q1Profit,Q2Profit")] Worker worker)
    {
        if (id != worker.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var employee = await _context.Workers.SingleOrDefaultAsync(w => w.Id == worker.Id);
                employee.Q1Rev = worker.Q1Rev;
                employee.Q2Rev = worker.Q2Rev;
                employee.Q1Cost = worker.Q1Cost;
                employee.Q2Cost = worker.Q2Cost;


                _context.Update(employee);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!WorkerExists(worker.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(worker);
    }
```

This way allows me to edit only the values I want while still preserving the originals and calculations, if anyone can explain why this way works and the other doesn't I would appreciate it.

Comment: worker is your model. This is a post action. I don't believe that you should have to explicitly bind to Q1Profit or Q2Profit. When the model is bound in the view, the getters should calculate. Maybe I don't understand the problem.

Comment: When I `Create` a new instance of `Worker` Everything works fine and is saved and `Q1Profit` and `Q2Profit` are calculated. However if I `Edit` any property, say I decide to edit `Q1Rev`, it saves that new value, but it does not calculate `Q1Profit` instead it sets `Q1Profit` to 0. Even though it saved the correct value in `Create`

Comment: Well, I don't see any line that updates Q1Profit. You need to add employee.Q1Profit = worker.Q1Profit and same for Q2Profit.

Comment: Are you using Worker as both a model and an Entity Framework entity?

Comment: Yes, I am using Worker to reference  the value in the database